# Cloning not working correctly in IE6 with Jquery 1.10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

Now before you start telling me not to support IE6, just know it's not my decision and i'm stuck with a legacy system forcing me downwards to ie6 and when possible to ie8... I can't even deliver on FF or Chrome, sad days!

My problem comes from the fact that a specific machine setup (IE6 via a Citrix metaframe) is unable to clone elements.

For example:

```
//clone the elements
var oldProd = $(this).parents('.wdm-ui-prodHierarchy-fieldset');
var newProd = $(this).parents('.wdm-ui-prodHierarchy-fieldset').clone(false);

//Change the ids in the cloned items
prodStructSequence++;
$('#console').append('<p>old prod number: ' + oldProd.attr('number') + '</p>');
newProd.attr('number', prodStructSequence);
$('#console').append('<p>old prod number: ' + oldProd.attr('number') + '</p>');
$('#console').append('<p>new prod number: ' + newProd.attr('number') + '</p>');
newProd.find('select.prod-struct-service').each(function(i){ this.id = increment(this.id, prodStructSequence); } );
newProd.find('select.prod-struct-product').each(function(i){ this.id = increment(this.id, prodStructSequence); } );
newProd.find('select.prod-struct-action').each(function(i){ this.id = increment(this.id, prodStructSequence); } );
newProd.find('.cloneButton').each(function(i){ this.number = increment(this.number, prodStructSequence); } );
newProd.find('.removeButton').each(function(i){ this.number = increment(this.number, prodStructSequence); } );
```

I also tried directly using:

```
newProd.number = prodStructSequence;
```

But my result is always this:

```
old prod number: 1
old prod number: 2
new prod number: 2
Found element.number: 2
Found element.number: 2
```

Do you have a solution, maybe not using clone, i just want this to work to move on to something else.

Versions:

1. IE6.0.3790.3959 + Citrix + jQuery 1.10.2 doesn't works
2. IE6.0.2900.5512 + Windows Xp Mode SP3 + jQuery 1.10.2 works
3. IE8, FF,
   Chrome all work

Comment: @user2751288 I think he was clear enough in the question for that to be a pointless comment.

Comment: It's difficult without markup to be sure what may or may not help, unless of course there are some experts in the particular field of "crap ancient browsers" here!  Does the element you are cloning have an ID?  Could we possibly see the markup for it?

Comment: Sorry archer didn't see it

Comment: @user2751288 I can't talk.  I've done my fair share of not reading thoroughly today :p

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in cloneNode()?

Comment: @Archer Yes there are ids on each item although since they are dynamic, i don'T really see the point, it could be the problem actually... I'll see if removing the ids change anything

Comment: @Archer i just looked at the code and did a quick project wide search, there are tons of references to those id's hugh!!! These guys have no SOLID concept!

Comment: We must work at the same place :p

Comment: @Archer oh so you work for a BUSINESS on EARTH? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting most of the code cause nothing worked. The end result is that i pre-generated X number of lines instead of cloning and show/hide the group/line of fields and just reset them on demand.

Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with `clone()` but there might be a different way to accomplish this:

```
$(this).parents('.wdm-ui-prodHierarchy-fieldset').wrap('<span class="save_me_for_later" />');

var newProd = $('.save_me_for_later').html();

$('.save_me_for_later').remove();
```

Comment: I'll look into this tomorrow as a last resort, thanks